# Joomla: JFactory::getApplication('site') returns error when refreshing much

Tags: php, joomla

When I switch pages to much on my website or refresh a couple of times fast, i get the 'Application Instantiation Error' of factory.php

Here is the code
index.php

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
```

Here is the code in /libraries/joomla/factory.php

```
public static function getApplication($id = null, array $config = array(), $prefix = 'J')
{
    if (!self::$application)
    {
        if (!$id)
        {
            throw new Exception('Application Instantiation Error', 500);
        }

        self::$application = JApplication::getInstance($id, $config, $prefix);
    }
    return self::$application;
}
```

Is there a way to solve this? Is this a Joomla error or a database error?

Hope somebody can help.

Comment: There is a separate stack exchange site for Joomla, I would suggest you ask there.  [joomla.se]

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a problem with the connection to the database (possibly some limit imposed by your host). Check your logs to see what is going on (this one `/usr/local/apache/logs/error_log` ). If you can't find anything in the logs then talk to your host about this problem (ask them to switch you to a higher plan if they try blaming the CMS).